# Is it possible to define survey questions in different languages?

Tags: survey-list, localization

Is it possible to define SharePoint survey questions in different languages, such that a user can choose if he wants to take the survey in a specific language?

One solution that we have considered is having a branch for each language, but wondering if anyone has a better solution?

Comment: In the end we found that the SharePoint Survey did not match our requirements and used a different 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you are asking the same questions across all of the languages, so I don't see how you could then compare the results easily given the branching based on language.  There would be no easy way to see the responses for same question across all of the languages.

I would suggest creating a separate survey for each language.  You may be able to create it once, save it as a template so the structure is defined and then create the other languages based on the template.  Of course, you will have to back in and change the text to match the language.  This would at least give the possibility of matching the responses to each question across the various languages.  The reporting may need to be a more custom solution or possibly SSRS if that is available.